# AngularJS translation with pluralization using angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, translation, angular-translate, pluralize

Hello I need to make translations with pluralization depending on a value, but can't find how to do that.

for example I have variable `peopleCount`.

1. `peopleCount = 1` translations should be: english: `{{ peopleCount }} person likes this` lithuanian: `{{ peopleCount }} zmogus tai megsta`
2. if `peopleCount` is more than 1 english translation would be: `{{ peopleCount }} people like this`.

but for lithuanian translations:

3. if `peopleCount` is between 2 and 9 or any number ending with those         numbers except numbers which ends with numbers provided in 4th rule (example: 225, 249, 210 <--- these are correct numbers. and incorrent ones: 215, 250...).         it would be `{{ peopleCount }} zmones tai megsta`
4. if count is between 10 and 20 or 30, 40 or any other number ending    with a zero like 150 or 90 it would be `{{ peopleCount }} zmoniu tai megsta`

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Just a note that proper English grammar would be "5 people like this" (not likes).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Angular-translate has service with functionality of MessageFormat which is really powerful and also has built-in locale for lithuanian. [Article about MessageFormat and angular-translate.](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/14_pluralization)

**Installing**

You can install this package via bower:

```
$ bower install angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat
```

After that include necessary scripts with MessageFormat and angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat in that order:

```
<script src="path/to/messageformat.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat.js"></script>
```

And finally in your config function call useMessageFormatInterpolation function from $translateProvider:

```
$translateProvider.useMessageFormatInterpolation();
```

---

**Usage**

After installing `angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat` into your app you can work with it.

For example, you can create english localization for code 'PEOPLE' as this:

```
{
    "PEOPLE" : "{peopleCount, plural, one {There is one man (in lithuanian)} few {# zmones tai megsta} other {# zmoniu tai megsta}}"
}
```

And than use it in your html like this:

```
<span translate="PEOPLE" translate-values="{peopleCount: 12}" translate-interpolation="messageformat"></span>
```

The output will be: "12 zmones tai megsta".

Comment: Still wondering if there is a way of making this with more options with some kind of statements instead of `one`, `few` and `other` ?

Comment: You can read more on [github](https://github.com/SlexAxton/messageformat.js/). There is also `select` declaration, which isn't trully statement, but maybe will be helpful for your needs. With select you can create something like this: `"PEOPLE" : "{peopleCount, select, 1 {one man} 2 {two men} other {# people}}"`

Comment: How can the output be "12 zmones tai megsta", when the value of `peopleCount` is 5? 12 != 5

Comment: It didn't work for me with
`$translateProvider.useMessageFormatInterpolation();`
but looking in the source code I found out I need
`$translateProvider.addInterpolation('$translateMessageFormatInterpolation');`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work for your scenario:

```
<ng-pluralize count="peopleCount"
             when="{
                 'one': 'zmogus tai megsta',
                 'few': '{} zmones tai megsta',
                 'other': '{} zmoniu tai megsta'}">
</ng-pluralize>
```

You can look into this for more details.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPluralize
and for language specific plural strings here:
http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this without `angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat`

My case is:
I have resource bundle lables:
`label.myItem=You have {{count}} item`
`label.myItems=You have {{count}} items`

in HTML I have written like this:

```
<ng-pluralize count="itemCount"
       when="{'one':'{{&quot;label.myItem&quot; | translate:{count: itemCount} }}',
             'other':'{{&quot;label.myItems&quot; | translate: {count: itemCount} }}' }">
</ng-pluralize>
```

here `itemCount` will be a `$scope` variable.

By this way you no need to install any new angular Package.

**Output is:**
When I have 1:

> You have 1 item

When I have 2(More than 1):

> You have 2 items